# Amazon S3 single upload limit 1GB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I am uploading to Amazon S3 (not using multi-part upload) and am having issues when trying to upload a file that is larger that ~1GB. The issue is that the object is empty in the s3 bucket, there is no error.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html) states that this should support up to 5GBs.

Typically it takes me (with my connection) ~1 minute to upload a 50mb file and for a 1gb file it takes several minutes. When I tried a 2-4gb file it would quickly "succeed" in uploading after a couple seconds but of course empty in the s3 bucket path. Does anyone know why I am seeing this behavior?

Comment: Can you show your logic that you are using to upload an object to an Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: Probably you can also enable some debug/verbose logging that could help pin down the issue.

Comment: Please Edit your Question and show us your code.